# Can a user buffer always be mapped into a contiguous kernel virtual address?

Tags: linux-kernel

If a user creates a buffer (either through malloc or static configuration), can this buffer always be mapped into the kernels address space contiguously?

I want to have the kernel loop over the array in user space without copying it via copy_from_user and then copy_to_user.

Given that the user presents the address/length of the buffer to the kernel via an ioctl, what calls do I make at the kernel layer to get a kva for the entire buffer.

Thanks.

Comment: When this ketnel loop is executed? (By which event)

Comment: @Alex: In user context, in a later ioctl call.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, if you are in the context of your application (you are making ioctl), nothing stops you to write/read directly from user address from kernel except swapping (if this is a case in your system). So you can use [mlock](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mlock.2.html) to pin your ram buffer in userspace. You don't need kva here, you might use user address. I'am not completely sure, but this should work. Have you tried?